# Angular Observable need to complete first

Tags: angular, promise, async-await, rxjs, observable

```
@Input() list: string[];

ngOnInit() : void {
   this.valueMap = new Map<any, any>();
   this.getDataFromService();
   this.buildContainer();
}

private getDataFromService(): void {
  this.list.forEach(value-> {
      this.fetchService(value).subscribe(data ->{
          this.valueMap.set(value,data);
          }
       )
   })
}

private buildContainer(): void {
   console.log(this.valueMap.size); // shows always 0 even when service returns the data 
 }
```

Now thing is that I have to use this `valueMap`  in the method `buidlContainer()` ,
hence I need to get the complete map first from service. And when I use that map in buildConatainer() it shows me undefined .

I understood that this is some async call issue . Also , I can not call method buildContainer() for each value in .subscribe() as that would not be better idea.
So  , I have to compute the Map first before processing that further..

Any help is appreciated and **i can not modify the service from returning Observable to return Promise**

**i want to do as below**

```
private buildContainer(): void {
   for([key,data] of this.valueMap) {
      -----some code----
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the disadvantage (or *advantage* depending how you look at it) of introducing reactive paradigm to your code. A single point of reactive procedure would gradually creep into other parts of the code either partially or completely.

So I'd recommend you to make the `valueMap` reactive as well and make it respond based on the changes in `getDataFromService()` service. One way would to make the `valueMap` variable a RxJS [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with a buffer of 1. So it'll buffer (or hold) it's last value pushed to it and emit it immediately upon subscription.

Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { take, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

valueMap: ReplaySubject<Map<any, any>> = ReplaySubject<Map<any, any>>(1);
completed$ = new Subject<any>();

@Input() list: string[];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.valueMap = new Map <any, any>();
  this.getDataFromService();
  this.buildContainer();
}

private getDataFromService(): void {
  forkJoin(this.list.map(value => this.fetchService(value))).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.completed$)             // <-- close subscription upon component `ngOnDestroy` hook trigger
  ).subscribe(
    data => {
      let map = new Map<any, any>();
      data.forEach((item, i) => {
        map.set(this.list[i], item);
      });
      this.valueMap.next(map);
    }
  );
}

private buildContainer(): void {
  this.valueMap.asObservable().pipe(
    take(1)               // <-- emit only the first notification and complete
  ).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(this.valueMap.size);
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.completed$.next();
  this.completed$.complete();
}
```

I've also used RxJS [`forkJoin()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) function to combine multiple observables and [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) operator close the subscription when the component is destroyed.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7yui52)

In the example, I've used [`jsonplaceholder`](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) API to mock some HTTP calls in the `fetchService()` function.

Note:

1. The `forkJoin()` will emit only if all the observables complete. If you're dealing with a stream of data, you will have to replace it with either [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineLatest) or [`zip`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip) based on your requirement.
2. There is an obvious issue where if the `buildContainer()` function is called multiple times in quick successions, each will trigger individual subscriptions.

Comment: Nice approach! You can make it even more reactive if create the `valueMap` using map operator. See my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o5teiy

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `forkJoin` to wait for all observables to finish. `forkJoin` will bundle all observables into one. This observable can be returned and inside `ngOnInit` you subscribe to it and call `buildContainer`.

```
 @Input() list: string[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.valueMap = new Map<any, any>();
    this.getDataFromService().subscribe(_ => this.buildContainer());
  }

  private getDataFromService(): Observable<any> {
    return forkJoin(
      this.list.map(value =>
        this.fetchService(value).pipe(
          tap(data => this.valueMap.set(value, data))
        )
      )
    );
  }

  private buildContainer(): void {
    console.log(this.valueMap.size);
  }
```

The code would be even cleaner if you do not populate the `valueMap` inside the `tap` operator and instead use the result you get into your subscription function.

Comment: this is giving me error ```You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.```

Comment: my code is ```private getDataFromService(): Observable<any> {
                         return forkJoin(
                              this.sampleMap.forEach((value,key) 
                                   => {
                                        this.fetchService(value).pipe(
                                            tap(data => this.valueMap.set(key,data))
                                         )
                                      })
                                   );
                      }```

Comment: ```sampleMap``` is the map which has [key,value] pair.. i have changed this.list to this.sampleMap

Comment: @DeepakSharma You have to use `map` instead of `forEach` to return an array of observables instead of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **buildContainer** from **ngOnInit** and  Call the method inside the **subscribe**

```
 private getDataFromService(): void {
    this.list.forEach((value, index) -> {
        this.fetchService(value).subscribe(data ->{
            this.valueMap.set(value,data);
                   }
         )
         if(this.list.length-1 == index){
          this.buildContainer(); // call here
         }
     })
  }
```

Comment: i can not call for each value of map or each data from service... i need to call that method..only when all calls to service are finished...means i have the Map ready

Comment: @surendrakumar Since the buildContainer happens outside the subscribe, its executed before the async operations finished.