# Observable Errror : You provided 'undefined' where

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, observable

```
@Input() changeStoreKeyToChangeTypeMapping:Map<any,any>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.configToMetadataMap = new Map<any,any>();
    this.buildConfigMetaDataMap().subscribe(_ => this.init());
}

private buildConfigMetaDataMap(): Observable<any> {
        return forkJoin(
             this.changeStoreKeyToChangeTypeMapping.forEach((searchEntry,configKey) => {
                 this.configDataFetchService.getConfigMetadata(searchEntry.configId).pipe(
                     tap(metaData => this.configToMetadataMap.set(configKey,metaData))
                 )
             })
        );
    }
```

This is giving me Error

```
 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable
```

I want that i complete all the API calls in the method buildConfigMetaDataMap() and returns a final map so that i can use in init() method

Comment: haha) are you chaining the questions? you may ask on your latest question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the keyword `return` in the arrow function. Also you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function instead of `forEach`. Try the following

```js
private buildConfigMetaDataMap(): Observable <any> {
  return forkJoin(
    this.changeStoreKeyToChangeTypeMapping.map((searchEntry, configKey) => {
      return this.configDataFetchService.getConfigMetadata(searchEntry.configId).pipe(
        tap(metaData => this.configToMetadataMap.set(configKey, metaData))
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Note:

1. To understand why you need the `return`, you could refer my answer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
2. Assuming this question is related to your previous question, I've provided a different [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931497/6513921) there that doesn't use RxJS `tap` operator. It is better not to resort to `tap` *side-effect* when compute intensive tasks are involved.

Comment: i added return also..but same error i m getting  ```ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a....```